# mysql subquery using laravel's eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was wondering how I'd execute subqueries in eloquent. here's the gist containing the subquery I want to execute and the the db that I'm using with the eloquent model structure.

```
//the query I want to execute
select p.title, c.total
from posts as p,
(select post_id as id, count(*) as total from comments group by post_id) as c
where p.id=c.id


//my table structures
table posts -
id title content

table comments -
id post_id content


//eloquent models
class Post extends Eloquent{
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public function comments(){
        return $this->has_many('Comment', 'post_id');
    }
}

class Comment extends Eloquent{
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongs_to('Post', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

basically I want to use eloquent to execute the query which contains a subquery. I know I could use DB::query(); method to execute the raw query or may be try using join but I wanna stick to eloquent. any kind of architectural suggestion is welcomed too cause I might be missing a way which can be followed using eloquent to get the same result without using the exact same query.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. There are no methods for that.

Comment: You will have to create a custom class method and use the fluent query builder. It won't be exactly what you want, but will do what you need. See the [Fluent Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent#aggregates)

Comment: Another option to get a comment count is to `Post::with('comments')` then just use the php `count()` method on the view.

Comment: thanks both of you and as far as I've found it's not directly possible so I'm sticking to the raw query execution option for now. 

@Cristian yeah I checked out the static with method but you see this query I'd trying to execute is part of an even complex db query and after debugging through I've figured out that if I could do it then I'd be able to do the rest without any issue. So the problem is using with() method doesn't go with the whole process here. I'll rethink the strategy and try creating a custom method later on. thanks for your response guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably so far there is no subquery support in Eloquent. However you could try:

1. execute the subquery and put the results in a temporary table, and then execute the main query referring to that table (do not forget to delete the temporary table)
2. Rewrite the query in a way that doesn't need to use subqueries (this is not always possible I assume).

For the second alternative your query could become:

```
select p.title, count(c.id) as total
  from posts as p
  left join comments as c on p.id=c.id
group by p.id
```

which I think it is equivalent and usually faster.

PS: I haven't tested the query since I do not have the tables, but I use this approach often. If there is any typo just let me know.

Comment: thanks for the help but I've altered the architecture a little and implemented the join() method from fluent query builder. working exactly I want it to right now :D  thanks again